# Need help implementing a special edge detector

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm implementing an approach from a research paper.  Part of the approach calls for a major edge detector, which the authors describe as follows:

1. Obtain DC image (effectively downsample by 8 for both width and height)
2. Calculate Sobel gradient of DC image
3. Threshold Sobel gradient image (using T=120)
4. **Morphological operations to clean up edge image**

Note that this **NOT** Canny edge detection -- they don't bother with things like non-maximum suppression, etc.  I could of course do this with Canny edge detection, but I want to implement things exactly as they are expressed in the paper.

That last step is the one I'm a bit stuck on.

Here is exactly what the authors say about it:

> After obtaining the binary
>   edge map from the edge detection process, a binary morphological
>   operation is employed to remove isolated edge pixels,
>   which might cause false alarms during the edge detection

Here's how things are supposed to look like at the end of it all (edge blocks have been filled in black):

[image]

Here's what I have if I skip the last step:

[image]

It seems to be on the right track.  So here's what happens if I do erosion for step 4:

[image]

I've tried combinations of erosion and dilation to obtain the same result as they do, but don't get anywhere close.  Can anyone suggest a combination of morphological operators that will get me the desired result?

Here's the binarization output, in case anyone wants to play around with it:

[image]

And if you're really keen, here is the source code (C++):

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

using cv::Mat;
using cv::Size;

#include <stdio.h>

#define DCTSIZE 8
#define EDGE_PX 255

/*
 * Display a matrix as an image on the screen.
 */
void
show_mat(char *heading, Mat const &m)
{
    Mat clone = m.clone();

    Mat scaled(clone.size(), CV_8UC1);
    convertScaleAbs(clone, scaled);

    IplImage ipl = scaled;

    cvNamedWindow(heading, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
    cvShowImage(heading, &ipl);
    cvWaitKey(0);
}

/*
 * Get the DC components of the specified matrix as an image.
 */
Mat
get_dc(Mat const &m)
{
    Size s = m.size();
    assert(s.width  % DCTSIZE == 0);
    assert(s.height % DCTSIZE == 0);

    Size dc_size = Size(s.height/DCTSIZE, s.width/DCTSIZE);

    Mat dc(dc_size, CV_32FC1);
    cv::resize(m, dc, dc_size, 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);

    return dc;
}

/*
 * Detect the edges:
 *
 * Sobel operator
 * Thresholding
 * Morphological operations
 */
Mat
detect_edges(Mat const &src, int T)
{
    Mat sobelx    = Mat(src.size(), CV_32FC1);
    Mat sobely    = Mat(src.size(), CV_32FC1);
    Mat sobel_sum = Mat(src.size(), CV_32FC1);

    cv::Sobel(src, sobelx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3, 0.5);
    cv::Sobel(src, sobely, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3, 0.5);

    cv::add(cv::abs(sobelx), cv::abs(sobely), sobel_sum);

    Mat binarized = src.clone();
    cv::threshold(sobel_sum, binarized, T, EDGE_PX, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    cv::imwrite("binarized.png", binarized);

    //
    // TODO: this is the part I'm having problems with.
    //

#if 0
    //
    // Try a 3x3 cross structuring element.
    //
    Mat elt(3,3, CV_8UC1);
    elt.at<uchar>(0, 1) = 0;
    elt.at<uchar>(1, 0) = 0;
    elt.at<uchar>(1, 1) = 0;
    elt.at<uchar>(1, 2) = 0;
    elt.at<uchar>(2, 1) = 0;
#endif

    Mat dilated = binarized.clone();
    //cv::dilate(binarized, dilated, Mat());

    cv::imwrite("dilated.png", dilated);

    Mat eroded = dilated.clone();
    cv::erode(dilated, eroded, Mat());

    cv::imwrite("eroded.png", eroded);

    return eroded;
}

/*
 * Black out the blocks in the image that contain DC edges.
 */
void
censure_edge_blocks(Mat &orig, Mat const &edges)
{
    Size s = edges.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.height; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < s.width;  ++j)
    {
        if (edges.at<float>(i, j) != EDGE_PX)
            continue;

        int row = i*DCTSIZE;
        int col = j*DCTSIZE;

        for (int m = 0; m < DCTSIZE; ++m)
        for (int n = 0; n < DCTSIZE; ++n)
            orig.at<uchar>(row + m, col + n) = 0;
    }
}

/*
 * Load the image and return the first channel.
 */
Mat
load_grayscale(char *filename)
{
    Mat orig = cv::imread(filename);
    std::vector<Mat> channels(orig.channels());
    cv::split(orig, channels);
    Mat grey = channels[0];
    return grey;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert(argc == 3);

    int bin_thres = atoi(argv[2]);

    Mat orig = load_grayscale(argv[1]);
    //show_mat("orig", orig);

    Mat dc = get_dc(orig);
    cv::imwrite("dc.png", dc);

    Mat dc_edges = detect_edges(dc, bin_thres);

    cv::imwrite("dc_edges.png", dc_edges);

    censure_edge_blocks(orig, dc_edges);
    show_mat("censured", orig);
    cv::imwrite("censured.png", orig);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine any combination of morphological operations that would produce the same edges as detected by the supposedly correct result, given your partial result as input.

I note that the underlying image is different; this probably contributes to why your results are so different. The Lena image is fine for indicating the type of result but not for comparisons. Do you have the exact same image as the original authors ?

Comment: You're correct to notice that the underlying image is different.  In the case of the authors, they have JPEG-compressed it at around 0.3bpp.  However, I don't think this will make a difference to the edge detection, because that is being done using the DC image, not the original image.  AFAIK JPEG compression doesn't change the DC coefficients -- it mainly hammers the higher frequency components during quantization.

Comment: Firstly, I don't believe your get_dc() function gives the same data that the original authors are using in their algorithm. IIRC the DC component can be quantized in JPEG, just at higher accuracy than other components. Secondly, this is the Lena image; it is well known that this image has been copied and modified so many times that it is widely recommended to not use this for comparisons: even if your get_dc method is the same, the source image is probably different.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not easy to trust Lena images cause there are so many of them.  Unfortunately, the authors of the paper do not provide any other examples or intermediate output.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the paper ? I think that unless you have the actual test image for comparison you can't be sure that your implementation is wrong.

Comment: "Efficient DCT-domain blind measurement and reduction of blocking artifacts" by Liu and Bovik.  Unfortunately, it's behind a paywall.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors ? You may be surprised how willing researchers are to answer requests for details from a polite message. IMHO any reasonable researcher should be able to supply a link to test data for comparison at the very least. You may even be able to get hold of their own implementation. P.S. Next time please give year and journal for a reference: although papers can be behind paywalls sometimes another paper by the same authors describing the previous/next version of the algorithm is freely available.

Comment: I've given up and just used Canny instead of Sobel -- it gives similar results, but is slower (which is OK for research code).  If I **really** need this to work the way they described I might drop them a line, but for now, it's good enough.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

What the authors described could be implemented with connected component analysis, using 8way connectivity. I would not call that morphological though.

I do think you are missing something else: Their image does not have edges that are thicker than one pixel. Yours has. The paragraph you quoted only talks about removing isolated pixels, so there must be a step you missed or implemented differently.

Good luck!

Comment: It can be done in a number of different ways (non-max suppression or Hilditch algorithm, for example).  As you point out, this isn't really a morphological method.  I've implemented things to the letter so far, so I'm beginning to suspect that there is something missing from the approach in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is a kind of erode or open that is, in a sense, 4-way and not 8-way. The default morphological kernel for OpenCV is a 3x3 rectangle (`IplConvKernel` with `shape`=`CV_SHAPE_RECT`). This is pretty harsh on thin edges.

You might want to try eroding with a 3x3 custom `IplConvKernel` with `shape`=`CV_SHAPE_CROSS`.
If you need an even finer filter, you may want to try eroding with 4 different `CV_SHAPE_RECT` kernels of size 1x2, 2x1 with the anchor in (0,1) and (1,0) for each.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your input image has a much higher resolution that the test input image, which can explain the fact less edges are detected - the changes are more smooth.

Second of all, since the edges are thresholded to 0, try dilation on smaller neighborhoods (e.g. compare each pixels with 4 original neighbors (in a non-serial manner)) to get rid of isolated edges.